# Explaining this proof without words for $\frac{\pi}{4} = 2 \arctan\frac{1}{3} + \arctan\frac{1}{7}$

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, proof-without-words

Proof of Hutton's 1776 formula:

[image]

Why does the figure establish this identity?

$$
    \frac{\pi}{4} = 2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)
$$

Comment: On a text based website "without words" is going to be hard!

Comment: That diagram suggests $2\arctan \frac 13 + \arctan \frac 17 = \frac {\pi}{4}.$ $m\angle BAG = \arctan \frac 17, m\angle GAH = \arctan \frac 13,m\angle HAC = \arctan \frac 13,m\angle BAC = \frac \pi4$

Comment: @user317176 which is correct by the way, so either OP or their source made a typo.

Comment: Please, be "professional" : correct your formula into the formula given by @user317176.

Comment: @user317176 I know it is trivial that these are right angles, but how can I actually prove that they are?

Comment: You have to assume the grid is a grid of uniform squares. Otherwise the diagram doesn't even represent the theorem it's supposed to prove. The rest of the proof is just a bunch of similar triangles and knowing the tangent of $\frac\pi4$.

Comment: @Sam Vincent : take $A=0, H= (6,3), G=(7,1)...$ You have for example $(G-H|H-A)=((1,-2)|(6,3))=1\times 6+(-2)\times 3=0$

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen: I have never seen the notation $(G-H|H-A)$ before in this context. From your calculation, it appears to be equivalent to the dot product $(G-H)\cdot(H-A)$. Is your notation actually defined as an alternative to the dot, or as something else (perhaps for instructional purposes)?

Comment: How do you prove that they are right angles?  We must assume that the grid is ortho-normal... You can either say that the slope of $\overline {GC}$ is the negative reciprocal as the slope of $\overline {FH}$ or you can say that $\triangle AFH$ is isosceles and its median is perpendicular to the base.  Or, you can use the Pythagorean Theorem to find all of the side lengths.

Comment: @blue : yes, it is the dot product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be the angle $GAB$, let $\beta$ be the angle $HAB$, and let $\gamma$ be the angle $CAB$.

Notice that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{\pi}{4}$ since the triangle $ACD$ is right and $\tan(A)=5/5$.

Notice also that the angles $AHC$ and $AHG$ are $\frac{\pi}{2}$ since $AH$ bisects the line segment $CG$ and the lengths of $AC$ and $AG$ are equal.

With the Pythagorean theorem and basic trigonometry definitions, $\tan\alpha=\frac17$, $\tan\beta=\frac{\sqrt 5}{3\sqrt 5}$, and $\tan\gamma=\frac{\sqrt 5}{3\sqrt 5}$. Hence $\alpha=\arctan(1/7)$ and $\beta=\gamma=\arctan(1/3)$. It follows that

$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\alpha+\beta+\gamma=2\arctan\frac13+\arctan\frac17.$$

---

[image: Modified version of the original diagram.]

Comment: In claiming that $\angle AHC$ and $\angle AHG$ are right angles, it is not enough to observe that $AH$ bisects $CG$; a median is only an altitude in an isosceles triangle, so you'd need to have already established, for instance, that $AG=AC$. ... That said, it may be a bit easier to note that $AH$ and $CG$ each determine "$1$-by-$2$" right triangles with various grid points, and that, say, $\angle AHC$ and $\angle AHG$ are each the sum of (necessarily complementary) acute angles from two such triangles.

Comment: @blue good point. One can notice that the lengths of $AG$ and $AC$ are both $\sqrt{50}$. Or if not wedded to standard geometry proofs, one could check that vectors "along" $AH$ and $CG$ are perpendicular, or compute the slope of lines along those line segments, etc.

Comment: It is not  justified the perpendicularity of $AH$ and $CG$. It is better to argue that  $AC=AG=\sqrt{50}$.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to attract your attention on the fact that this relationship, here interpreted under a geometrical setting, can also be interpreted in a very easy way under a purely algebraic setting using **complex numbers**.

Indeed, consider identity :

$$50(1+i)=(3+i)^2(7+i)\tag{1}$$

Dividing (1) by $50 \sqrt{2}$ gives complex numbers with modulus $1$ :

$$\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}}=\left(\frac{(3+i)}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2\frac{(7+i)}{\sqrt{50}}\tag{2}$$

Now, you get the desired relationship by equating arguments on each side of (2), knowing that, due to the fact that *all angles are in* $[0, \pi/4]$ :

$$\begin{cases}\arg(z_1z_2)&=&\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)\\ \arg(a+ib)&=&\arctan \frac{b}{a}\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

**Remark :** relationship (1) can be considered in the ring of "Gaussian integers" (the set of complex numbers with integer real and imaginary parts).